# Recursion maze in java

Tags: java, recursion, maze

This program doesn't work, but meanwhile it has no error notice...Every time I entered a starting point, the starting point will show up, but no path to the Ending point nor the path it through. the program has a 7*11 Maze, "B" presents obstacle and a fixed ending point which presents as "X" and what the program would do is, you can enter a coordinate into it to make it as your starting point. Then the program would find a way from your starting point to the end (also the path will be shown in "O"). I tried to use recursion during this process, however it wouldn't work, and I don't know why. Please help me out guys.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Maze {
private static final Maze[][] String = null;
String[][] Maze=new String[7][11];
int x,y;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String name;
    int k=0,x1,y1;
    Maze M=new Maze();
    System.out.println("Hello there, would you like to provide your name, please?");
    name=M.Name();
    M.Maze=M.Set(M.Maze);
    M.Print(M.Maze);
    while (k==0){
        System.out.println(name+", now please enter coordinate of the starting point");
        System.out.println("The left top point would be (0,0)");
        System.out.println("Now, please enter the x value:");
        M.x=M.Input();
        System.out.println("And then, please enter the y value");
        M.y=M.Input();
        if (M.Maze[M.y][M.x]==" "){
            M.Maze[M.y][M.x]="$";
            k=1;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry, you cannot put your starting point there, please try again");
    }
    M.Process(M.x,M.y);
    M.Print(M.Maze);
    System.out.println("$ is the Starting Point");
    System.out.println("X is the Ending Point");
    System.out.println("O is the Path");
}
public static String Name() throws IOException{
    String name;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    name=br.readLine();
    return name;
}
public static int Input()throws IOException{
    int i;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    i=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    return i;
}
public static String[][] Set(String Maze[][]){
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<11;j++){
            Maze[i][j]=("B");
        }
    }
    Maze[1][1]=Maze[2][1]=Maze[3][1]=Maze[4][1]=Maze[5][1]=Maze[1][2]=Maze[1][3]=Maze[2][3]=Maze[3][3]=Maze[5][3]=Maze[3][4]=Maze[5][4]=Maze[1][5]=Maze[2][5]=Maze[3][5]=Maze[5][5]=Maze[3][6]=Maze[4][6]=Maze[5][6]=Maze[1][7]=Maze[2][7]=Maze[2][7]=Maze[3][7]=Maze[5][7]=" ";
    Maze[6][7]="X";
    Maze[1][8]=Maze[3][8]=Maze[1][9]=Maze[3][9]=Maze[4][9]=Maze[5][9]=" ";
    return Maze;
}
public static boolean Process(int x1, int y1){
    Maze M=new Maze();
    if (Move(M.Maze,x1,y1)){
        if (End(x1,y1))
            return true;
    }
    else{
        M.Maze[y1][x1]="1";
        if (Process(x1-1,y1)){
            M.Maze[y1][x1]="O";
            return true;
        }
        else if(Process(x1+1,y1)){
            M.Maze[y1][x1]="O";
            return true;
        }
        else if (Process(x1,y1-1)){
            M.Maze[y1][x1]="O";
            return true;
        }
        else if (Process(x1,y1+1)){
            M.Maze[y1][x1]="O";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean Move(String Maze[][],int x1, int y1){
    if (x1<0||y1<0||x1>6||y1>10)
        return false;
    if ((Maze[y1][x1]=="B")||Maze[y1][x1]=="1")
        return false;
    return true;
}
public static boolean End(int x1, int y1){
    if ((y1==7)&&(x1==5))
        return true;
    return false;
}
public static void Print(String Maze[][]){
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<11;j++){
            System.out.print(Maze[i][j]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe 1) what this program is supposed to do, 2) *how* you think it does what it is supposed to do?

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: And please don't call your array of `Maze` objects `String` and your array of `String` objects `Maze`.  In fact, it's best if you use lower case letters for your variable names, so as to distinguish them from the class names.

Comment: Sorry, I should change my array's name. This is easy to fix. BTW there are no error showed up, program is run-able, it's just it doesn't work as I expected

Comment: And, frankly, put it through a debugger didn't show anything up... I don't know why, I want the program shows all the way it tried(including dead end and the path to the end). But the program comes out with nothing....@DavidWallace

Comment: Sorry, my bad, first of all, the program has a 7*11 Maze, "B" presents obstacle and a fixed ending point which presents as "X" and what the program would do is, you can enter a coordinate into it to make it as your starting point. Then the program would find a way from your starting point to the end (also the path will be shown in "O"). I tried to use recursion during this process, however it wouldn't work, and I don't know why.. @Lutz Horn

Comment: So, if you stepped through it with a debugger, at what point did its behaviour deviate from what you expected?

Comment: um...problem resolved, my friend helped me out, still thank you guys! It was the condition problem, I has some problems about the Process method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what you want to do with this line, since it is used nowhere:

```
private static final Maze[][] String = null;
```

I found several issues in your code:

1. Every time your code enters the `Process`-method, a new instance of `Maze` is created with `Maze M=new Maze();`. The new instances don't know the extra markings which you made in the steps before (like the 1s), so it will switch back and forth between two neighbouring fields until you get an StackOverflowError.
2. Also the new `Maze` instances are not initialized with the labytinth, because you didn't call `Set` on it. You should place the code of the `Set`-method in the constructor of `Maze`, so that this kind of error can't occur.
3. BUT your program dosen't even come this far. If you feed the `Process`-method the cooridinates of your start field, it will wonder: "Can I move to the specified field and if so, is it the end?". The answer to "can I move there?" is obviously yes, since you made sure that the start field is clear. The answer to "is this the end?" is no. `Process` returns true and stops.

   --> What you should do about it: place the recursive calls of `Process` into the if, not the else. You don't need the else.
4. To prevent the `StackOverflowError` from item 1 to occur (it does by now) pass an instance of `Maze` to the `Process`-method. Remember to do this everytime you call `Process` and be careful that it always is the same instance. Delete the lines that produce a new `Maze` instance in `Process`.
5. For now you are error free, but it still doesn't work. This is because you mixed up the x and y maximum indices in the `Move`-method. You declared the array like this: `String[][] Maze=new String[7][11];`. This means that the maximum x-index is 10 and the maximum y-index is 6. In `Move` you check the bounds like this: `if (x1<0||y1<0||x1>6||y1>10)`
6. Similar is true for the `End`-method. If you count of the 'X' in your labyrinth, it is the 8-th to the left and 6-the from the top. This corresponds with a y-index of 6 and a x-index of 7. You did `(y1==7)&&(x1==5)`

Now it works. The 1s are the paths the program tried.

I think you have noticed that you cannot call non-static methods from a static-mehtod like the main-mehtod. If you have an instance of an object, like the `M` in your code, you can call non-static methods on it with `M.<methodName>()`.

I would strongly advice you to study the object orientated design more closely as it seems you did not understand it.

Also it would be nice if you would adhere to the java naming conventions - only classes and such start with an uppercase letter, everything else starts with a lowercase letter (variables, methods, etc.). It makes things easier to read for those who are used to it, which would almost be everyone, who was taught in a class or with a book.

Comment: Thank you! I just saw ur reply, and my friend helped me to resolve my problem. but still thank you a lot!